# getJSONObject and subsequent getString returns null

Tags: java, php, android, json, post

This is a very straightforward question, but this error is very mysterious to me as I have not been able to find a solution or anyone else who has had this problem. I've also used a very similar technique in another activity and it worked just fine. I am making an android application which makes a `POST` request to a server. The response is a `JSONObject` that must be parsed into a number and another `JSONObject` which must also be parsed, and its values assigned to an array of `CurrentGame` objects. The first call to `getJSONObject` works fine, but calling `getString` on that JSONObject returns the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'java.lang.String com.xxxxx.xxxxx.CurrentGame.oppEmail' on a null object reference
```

Here is my java code:

```
private void handleResponse(JSONObject response){
    int numGroups = 0;
    try{
        numGroups = response.getInt("Number");
    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Number of Groups", String.valueOf(numGroups));

    CurrentGame[] currentGames = new CurrentGame[numGroups];
    JSONObject current;
    int yourTurn = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numGroups; i++){
        try{
            current = response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
            Log.i("Current JSONObject: ", String.valueOf(current));
            if(current.has("OppEmail")){
                currentGames[i].oppEmail = current.getString("OppEmail");
            }
            if(current.has("OppName")) {
                currentGames[i].oppName = current.getString("OppName");
            }
            if(current.has("Group")) {
                currentGames[i].group = current.getString("Group");
            }
            if(current.has("YourTurn")) {
                yourTurn = current.getInt("YourTurn");
            }
            if(yourTurn == 0){
                currentGames[i].yourTurn = true;
            }
            else{
                currentGames[i].yourTurn = false;
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the `JSONObject.has()` check at least be preventing this error?

I know the first `getInt()` and `getJSONObject` are working. Heres the Log:

```
06-21 21:58:56.644  20116-20116/com.xxxxx.xxxxx D/Response:﹕ {"Number":2,"0":{"Group":"Test Group 1","OppEmail":"xxxxx@xxxxx.edu","OppName":"MikeyP","YourTurn":0},"1":{"Group":"Test Group 2","OppEmail":"xxxxx@xxxxx.edu","OppName":"MikeyP","YourTurn":1}}
06-21 21:58:56.644  20116-20116/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxt I/Number of Groups﹕ 2
06-21 21:58:56.644  20116-20116/com.xxxxx.xxxxx I/Current JSONObject﹕ {"Group":"Test Group 1","OppEmail":"xxxxxx@xxxxx.edu","OppName":"MikeyP","YourTurn":0}
```

Here's the server code:

```
$games['Number'] = $numgames;
if($numgames > 0){
  $i = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getgames)){
      $currGame['Group'] = $row['GroupName'];

      // Get the opponent's email and username
      if($row['Player1'] != $email){
          $opponent = $row['Player1'];
          $currGame['OppEmail'] = $opponent;
          $sql = "SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Email = '".$opponent."'";
          $username = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($username);
          $currGame['OppName'] = $row2['Username'];
      }
      else if($row['Player2'] != $email){
          $opponent = $row['Player2'];
          $currGame['OppEmail'] = $opponent;
          $sql = "SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Email = '".$opponent."'";
          $username = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($username);
          $currGame['OppName'] = $row2['Username'];
      }

      // Determine if it is this player's turn
      if($row['CurrentPlayer'] != $email){
          $currGame['YourTurn'] = 0;
      }
      else{
          $currGame['YourTurn'] = 1;
      }

      $games[$i] = $currGame;
      $i++;
  }
}
//Echo array of groups
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = json_encode($games);
echo $response;
```

Thank you in advance for any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here. I know similar questions have been asked about `getString()` returning `null`, but having read them all I'm still very stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is caused by :

```
currentGames[i].oppEmail = current.getString("OppEmail");
```

line.

Because `currentGames` Array is initialized with size 2 but not added any item of type `CurrentGame`.

Instead of using `currentGames[i].oppEmail` create a object of `CurrentGame` class add all values then add it in `currentGames` Array like:

```
CurrentGame objCurrentGame=new CurrentGame();
if(current.has("OppEmail")){
  objCurrentGame.oppEmail = current.getString("OppEmail");
}
... same for other fields 
...
//Add objCurrentGame to Array
currentGames[i]=objCurrentGame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing json this way is not robust and error prone, it is recommended to use such libraries as

- [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)
- [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.4)
- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

as these open source libraries offer stable implementation for such purposes and there is no need to reinvent the wheel yourself.

example:

```
YourPojoClass obj = new Gson().fromJson("{SomeJsonString}", YourPojoClass.class);
```

In this way, you get the strongly typed pojo instance.You don't even need write the POJO class yourself, and there are many online service that can generate the POJO class out of json strings:

- http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
- http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/